# How to update a value using forms and services on angular?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I have some issue in updation of value using reactive forms and services?
i found the problem. its in component --> updateData()-->that arguments..

pls help me to clear this problem.. i dont know which argument i need to pass? 
i found the problem. its in component --> updateData()-->that arguments..

pls help me to clear this problem.. i dont know which argument i need to pass?

HTML:

```
 <form [formGroup]="group">
        <div> &nbsp;  &nbsp; Id<input formControlName="Id"/></div>
        <br> 
      <div> &nbsp;  &nbsp; Name<input formControlName="Name"/></div>
      <br> 
     <div> &nbsp;  &nbsp; Title<input formControlName="Title"/></div>
      <br>
      <div> &nbsp;  &nbsp; Author<input formControlName="Author"/></div>
      <br>
    </form>
    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <button (click)="updateData()">Update</button> &nbsp;
    <div>
    <button (click)="listData()">List</button>
    {{list | json}}
    </div>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ControlService } from '../control.service';
import { NgForOf } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-forms',
  templateUrl: './forms.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./forms.component.css']
})
export class FormsComponent implements OnInit {
group:FormGroup;
list;
list1;
  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder, private service:ControlService) {
    this.group=this.fb.group({
      Id:[''],
      Name:[''],
      Title:[''],
      Author:[''],
    })
   }

ngOnInit() {

  }
listData(){
  this.service.userData().subscribe(res=>{
    console.log("list data",res);
    this.list=res;
  },error=>{
    console.log("error1",error);
  })
}
updateData(){
this.service.updateUserData({group.Name:this.list}).subscribe(res=>{
  console.log('update data',res);
  this.list1=res;
},error=>{
  console.log("error2",error);
})
}


}
```

service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ControlService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {}
userData(){
 return this.http.get('http://localhost:5000/user');
}
updateUserData(value){
  return this.http.put('http://localhost:5000/user/2',value);
 }

}
```

Comment: Please use `group.patchValue(data)` to set value to the group.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to get the data from the form, use this:

```
this.service.updateUserData(this.group.value).subscribe(...);
```

The `value` property of the form group provides all of the values from the form controls on the form.